# Dropping shadow on WinForm distorts interface

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dropshadow

I'm using the following code to create a Windows7 style drop shadow effect on my WinForms:

```
<DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig:=True)> _
Private Shared Function DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd As IntPtr, attr As Integer, ByRef attrValue As Integer, attrSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("dwmapi.dll")> _
Private Shared Function DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef pMarInset As Margins) As Integer
End Function

Private Function CreateDropShadow() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim val As Integer = 2
        Dim ret1 As Integer = DwmSetWindowAttribute(Me.Handle, 2, val, 4)

        If ret1 = 0 Then
            Dim m As New Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            Dim ret2 As Integer = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Me.Handle, m)
            Return ret2 = 0
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Probably dwmapi.dll not found (incompatible OS)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
    CreateDropShadow()
    MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
End Sub
```

The result of above code creates a nice drop shadow effect on my borderless winform, but it causes the UI to distort. All the controls and labels on my form aren't appearing properly, with text not readable.

Am I missing something here? I don't want to use the traditional drop shadow effect using CreateParams, its too 'boxy' look and doesn't give a nice shadow effect.

Here are screenshots of without shadow and with shadow:
[image: Form without drop shadow]
[image: Form with drop shadow]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering why this is working for you in the first place. I tried to call the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function with a maring of 0 for all sides and the result is that I don't get any drop shadow effect (Windows 7 SP1, x86). However, if I call it with margin 1 for each side I get the desired aero drop shadow. The only thing left to do was to overpaint the such created frame area with the form's background color. Otherwise I didn't notice any strange behavior.

Comment: Are you sure you have a borderless form?

Comment: When you mean with borderless form that the `FormBorderStyle` property is set to `None` then yes, I am sure.

Comment: Yes thats what I was talking about. See my question again, I've added screenshots now using the same code as in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  Dim m As New Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

There's a subtle mistake visible here, looks a lot like you are using  System.Drawing.Printing.Margins.  But that's **not** a type that's compatible with the Windows' MARGINS type.  Which is a *structure*, not a class.

So this just goes complete wrong, Windows reads nonsense instead of (0, 0, 0, 0).  And extends the frame into the *entire* client area.  Which then plays havoc on any control that draws with GDI, it is a 24bpp drawing api that leaves the alpha at 0 so anything that should be black becomes transparent instead.

Fix this by declaring a proper MARGINS structure:

```
Structure MARGINS
    Public Left, Right, Top, Bottom As Integer
End Structure
```

Comment: Yes that's definitley the problem, the screenshots show it clearly. For my test I added the correct structure so I wasn't able to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes that fixes it. And like @AndreasAdler said keeping MARGINS at zero wasn't producing shadow, so I changed it to 1 for all sides. Now works like a charm. What an invisible mistake. Thanks Hans.